# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with xfire-all-1.0 version

Tags: java

I facing problem with X-Fire-all-1.0 version jar. In our application we implemented webservices, for this we are using xfire-all-1.0.jar. Working fine with this. But some times on our Jboss console getting following exceptions. This is I am not getting always. As per my application requirement, when client sends the request to get list of merchants details [Our webservice returns the all the merchant details in success scenario] response document is preparing with the help of x-fire api. But some times getting following issue. How to resolve it.Is the bug in xfire-all-1.0.jar?

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.checkConcurrentModification(ContentList.java:940)
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.nextIndex(ContentList.java:829)
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.hasNext(ContentList.java:785)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl.AbstractWSDL.cleanImports(AbstractWSDL.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl.AbstractWSDL.updateImports(AbstractWSDL.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl11.builder.WSDLBuilder.write(WSDLBuilder.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl11.builder.WSDLBuilderAdapter.write(WSDLBuilderAdapter.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.DefaultXFire.generateWSDL(DefaultXFire.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.generateWSDL(XFireServletController.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.doService(XFireServletController.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServlet.doGet(XFireServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
19:58:05,722 ERROR [[XFireServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet XFireServlet threw exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.checkConcurrentModification(ContentList.java:940)
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.nextIndex(ContentList.java:829)
    at org.jdom.ContentList$FilterListIterator.hasNext(ContentList.java:785)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl.AbstractWSDL.cleanImports(AbstractWSDL.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl.AbstractWSDL.updateImports(AbstractWSDL.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl11.builder.WSDLBuilder.write(WSDLBuilder.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.wsdl11.builder.WSDLBuilderAdapter.write(WSDLBuilderAdapter.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.DefaultXFire.generateWSDL(DefaultXFire.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.generateWSDL(XFireServletController.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.doService(XFireServletController.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServlet.doGet(XFireServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: After getting this exception repeatedly, application not responding for client request. After restarting the server it is working fine, after multiple requests repeating the problem gain and again.

Comment: You should direct your issue at the xfire development team. This is most probably a bug in their implementation.